# Left Join VS Inner Join lesser rowcount mysql pdo php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, join

```
"SELECT *
   FROM property t1 
   LEFT 
   JOIN address t2 
     ON t1.pin = t2.pid 
    AND t1.status = t2.status 
   LEFT 
   JOIN ownerinfo t3 
     ON t1.pid = t3.pid 
    AND t1.status = t3.status 
   LEFT JOIN boundaries t4 
     ON t1.pid = t4.pid 
    AND t1.status = t4.status 
   LEFT 
   JOIN status t5 
     ON t1.pid = t5.pid 
    AND t1.status = t5.status 
   LEFT 
   JOIN references t6 
     ON t1.pid = t6.pid 
    AND t1.status = t6.status 
   LEFT 
   JOIN classification t7 
     ON t1.kind = t7.sysid 
   LEFT 
   JOIN oaddress t8 
     ON t1.basicinfo_id = t8.basicinfoid 
   LEFT 
   JOIN obasicinfo t9 
     ON t1.basicinfo_id = t9.id 
  WHERE t1.pid = :pid  
    AND t1.status = :status
 "
```

This is my query for left join. I used left join mainly because there will be a time or instance where in one of the tables will not have a related data with the others. But I still need to get the data of the related ones. If I use `INNER JOIN` I wont be able to get a result if that is the case. Currently `LEFT JOIN` does the job. But i get so much `rowcount()` that i get `out of memory`. For a 2 entry, on some instance I get `6144` record on other instance i get `12288` that is where i get the `out of memory` (Depending on the combination of which table have data and which have no data).

1. Should i just fill in all the tables during `insert` and use `INNER JOIN`?
2. Would `INNER JOIN` lessen or decrease the number of `rowcount()`?
3. What is best suited query to get much lesser `rowcount()`?

`UPDATE`

1. t1 has 2 entries
2. t2 has 1 entry
3. t3 has 2 entries
4. t4 has 1 entry
5. t5 and t6 has no entry
6. t7 has 15 entries
7. t8 has 21 entries
8. t9 has 12 entries

Comment: If you filled in all the tables and used an inner join wouldn't it return the same results as the left join does now since it doesn't omit?

Comment: One query does one thing. The other query does another thing. The answer depends on what you actually want.

Comment: I am not sure @JohnHalbert that is why i am asking if it would be the case. For example i fill in all the tables with the `pid` which will be used as a connection on all t able. Will i get much lesser rowcount?

Comment: maybe you can only select te columns you need, instead of select *. That way you may get a much smaller temp table and don't run out of memory

Comment: Forgetting the joins, how many records does `SELECT *
   FROM property t1  WHERE t1.pid = :pid  
    AND t1.status = :status` return.   You'll never get less than this with the left joins

Comment: I just want to be able to reduce the rowcount what will be my best option? use INNER JOIN have all the tables connected?

Comment: @Ray only two with the sample data i am working on right now. but some table like for instance `t2 another 2 entry t3 anotehr 4 entry and so on..`

Comment: @verhie i actually need all the columns. I will save them in an array then save it again in another table. Is there a way to transfer data from one table to another just by using an `ID` such in my case as `pid`?

Comment: Well I think it would be the same result as left join.  And I think that @verhie's suggestion might be something to consider, but you already limit your results with a WHERE, so it will depend on your design.

Comment: i think you have a duplicate in one of the joined tables, can you check that. Since you have exactly twice the data in the other instance

Comment: @verhie im sure that there are no duplicate. Let me write the actual number of record for each table in update

Comment: @BrownmanRevival I would do a count adding on each Join one at a time to see where you're getting the growth.  One or more of the joins i bringing in a lot of rows

Comment: @BrownmanRevival Does the number of row decrease if you add "GROUP BY t1.ID" ? If it doesn't it won't change a thing, since it means that you have 6144 rows filling your conditions. You can also use LIMIT to get your result in differents parts so you don't have a memory limit.

Comment: ok, since you've tagged php, can you not just do 8 separate queries and do the rest in php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its depend on your table structure maybe there are few values that return few times in the left tables, and than you received Cartesian

Comment: I read your comment over and over and reviewed my code i finally understood what you mean and this helped my lessen the rowcount. There are indeed values that are returned more than once. They are return by mutiple of rows that is why i am getting 12k and 6k rowcount

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about the schema, your application or the actual data in the table, I'm going to take a wild stab and grossly assume for each property `t1.pid` there are relatively few related records in each table.

If this is true, my guess for where your data is exploding is with one of the two table joins:

```
LEFT JOIN classification t7 
 ON t1.kind = t7.sysid 
LEFT JOIN oaddress t8 
 ON t1.basicinfo_id = t8.basicinfoid
```

One or both of these seem likely to not be specific enough all other JOINS include in their `ON` clause `t1.pid` linking back to the original `property` table.

Remove these two JOINS, then see if your result set shrinks significantly.  IF it does, add them back one at a time to figure out your growth issue.

Without more info on your scheme and the data there's not more I can provide.  Adding to the OP the `create table` statements for the listed tables would be useful.

Comment: Yeah if i remove those lines i get reduce rowcount but then my result is also affected..Would I get lesser rowcount if i use INNER JOIN? for instance like this one.

Comment: Forget the inner join for a second.  Add the create statements for the tables `property`, `classification`, and `oadress` to your post so we can figure out if there is something more specific we can do

Comment: Hey last question tried the comment above i used group by i return only 1 rowcount is this rowcount complete?

Comment: @BrownmanRevival  Ever better would be if you could include a sample few records from the `classification` and `oadress` tables

Comment: is there a jsfiddle like site but for php that you know of so i post it there for better understanding

Comment: @BrownmanRevival don't group by just the `t.pid` it's too broad a grouping

Comment: ok i will post the query that return the out of memory it is much bigger than this one is it ok?

Comment: that one is a smaller one different quesry i have another one bigger returns 12288 rowcount

Comment: i tried adding the id to all tables and use inner join i got even a bigger rowcount i get `24576` rowcount

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the relationships of the tables. Let's say just as an example you have 1000 properties, and every property has 2 classification records, then the total rowcount would be 2000, and so on. It depends on the logic you are after, and the structure you create.

If each joined table was supposed to be only ONE record maximum (ie the property table is the 'many side' of the relationship), then in THAT case it would never exceed 1000.

This is just the nature of joins and database structure.